# Tools for statically analyzing the size of a native Windows binary?

Tags: c++, windows, memory, profiling, memory-profiling

Are there such tools? If so, what are they called, and is there a generic, searchable term? "Image size profiler" doesn't seem to yield many results. I'm not even certain how you would tag this.

I'm looking for something that would take a native .exe or .dll, and using the .pdb file, would help elucidate why a binary is several megabytes in file size by visualizing what is taking up the most space. Hopefully capable of analyzing static variables/tables, code, and resources, and preferably free if possible.

Do tools exist to do the analysis statically, or is running it under a memory profiler the only option? Is there a free memory profiler that would help with the file size itself?

Comment: You can try to find a `readelf` program built for windows.

Comment: To the people voting to close: asking for a **specific** tool is off-topic because that is usually subjective. This question does not. It asks whether such tools exist at all, and the generic description. That is not subjective.

Comment: Still, it's asking for a tool. What was tried so far? Did the user try DUMPBIN and visualize the output somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done this manually on occasion, using a linker map file, which lists all the functions, their positions and lengths.
It would be nice if there were a tool to take 20 uniformly distributed "stabs" into the .exe or .dll and tell me the name of the function it lands in.
If I did this often enough I would write one.

However, a simple way to see what's accounting for most of the space is to simply look at the map file, in random locations, and see what functions are in there.

As an example of what I mean, I have seen files where large I/O classes, or Date classes, or container classes, were included just because there was one variable declared with such a class but not even used.
Or a local class could inherit from a general system class, causing tons of stuff to be linked in, when the local class doesn't actually need it.
This can be easily spotted by just eyeballing the map file.